# java.util.Lists in Gwt super dev mode debugger

Tags: intellij-idea, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

We recently decided to integrate Material Design into our mature GWT application and this has finally forced our hand on moving from Legacy dev Mode to Super dev mode.  We have this working fairly well using Chrome and Intellij IDE, 2016.2.  One lingering problem though is viewing Java containers (Lists, Maps, etc.) in the debugger.  In the screenshot below, the two expanded *supportingCopyWidgetPresenters* and *supportingCopyEventPageBlockContentElements* are both declared as *java.util.Lists*:

[image]

In case this is hard to read, the debugger is showing both lists values to be:

> array = Internal error: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 1386

Is there a special argument I need to pass to super dev mode to have it interpret Lists (and Maps, for that matter) correctly in the debugger?  Is this a matter of telling super dev mode to use a different JSON parser?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's odd - a `java.util.List` or some subtype is actually a Java Object, so is emulated as an object, not as a js list (which _should_ be used for Java Arrays). It looks like IntelliJ is incorrectly assuming that the JSON.stringify of a java list is just a flat array, which it clearly cannot be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with the version of Intellij.  This was answered in the [GWT google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Web-Toolkit/k8x9Y-Gidhw).